# How can I upload to SabreDAV using ITHit AjaxFileBrowser?

Tags: php, webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser, sabredav

Using two versions of AjaxFileBrowser by ITHit (the latest, 2_6_2_2135, and another purchased last year), I'm trying to connect to SabreDAV (two different versions: 1.8.12 and 2.1.2) but can't upload any files. Viewing files and directories works fine, and I can upload files using the built-in SabreDAV client. Also, I can use Postman to PUT a file to the SabreDAV server endpoint.

It appears that a 404 error on uploading a file is stopping the process. But I thought that the client would handle 404 errors on uploads (as the file doesn't exist). I should note that uploading a file that already exists works, and the file is updated.

I've written the support email on a different issue, and was asked to write here. Any takers? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

We have examined the this issue as well as SabreDAV code. This issue is caused by en exception in SabreDAV which does not process If-Modified-Since header correctly for PUT request. Note that If-Modified-Since is a valid header for PUT request according to HTTP standard.

To my understanding the If-Modified-Since is attached to a PUT request by IT Hit Ajax File Browser because of a bug in Google Chrome and Safari that prevented upload to function properly after get GET request with If-Modified-Since header.

We have verified that the issue in WebKit with PUT upload was fixed and we can probably remove the If-Modified-Since header (we are still looking if this would not break any functionality). Instead, in the future versions, we will add the If-Match and If-Not-Modified-Since headers to prevent the concurrent updates of the file during upload and pause-continue cycles.